# Using the appropriate data structure to return all calculations

Tags: c#

I am building a calculations library using c#. The library will have methods that would return individual calculations when called or it would return all the calculations in one go. I have used tuples for methods that return individual calculations. What do I do to return all calculations in one go. Currently I am trying to use a dictionary object. The method will receive Dictionary object of int and IEnumerable of double values. What datastructure do I use to return as dictionary doesnt make sense in this case. My return object in this example should contain the monthly and annual calculations for both Arthimethic mean and AverageGain.

Methods that return individual values

```
public (double Monthly, double Annual) ArithmeticMean(IEnumerable<double> ReturnsList)
{
    double returnList = ReturnsList.Mean();
    return (Monthly: returnList, Annual: returnList * Math.Pow(12, 0.5));
}

public (double Monthly, double Annual) AverageGain(IEnumerable<double> ReturnsList)
{
    double returnList = ReturnsList.GainMean();
    return (Monthly: returnList, Annual: returnList * Math.Pow(12, 0.5));
}
```

Method that should return both Arthimetic Mean and Average Gain for all funds. Note that there could be more calculations in future and it would involve returning Monthly and Annual of each calculations

So for e.g the ReturnsList dictionary input parameter would contain

collection of FundId and ReturnsList

```
1 , ReturnList
2, ReturnList
```

I would need to return

```
1, ArithmeticMeanMontlyValue,ArithmeticMeanAnnualValue
2, ArithmeticMeanMontlyValue,ArithmeticMeanAnnualValue
public Dictionary<int, double> RiskMatrixByFunds(Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<double>> ReturnsList)
{
    Dictionary<int, double> riskMatrix =new Dictionary<int, double>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<double>> entry in ReturnsList)
    {
        riskMatrix.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value.Mean());
    }
    return riskMatrix;
}
```

Comment: I would probably create a struct for the results of your "single value" methods, and return an Dictionary of string and that struct from your "calculate all"  method.

Comment: What stops you from using an IEnumerable ValueTuple as you had before?

Comment: Do you mean returning  IEnumerable ValueTuple for all calculations? How is it used

Comment: Define a struture and don't think more about the future, unforeseen works are always waiting for you in my experience.

Comment: Are you saying using structure overall over valuetuple ?

Comment: I am now confused between using valueTuple and structure. Could somebody tell me the best approach with an example of the returning all the calculations